# Why on earth does CEdit provide a copy/paste menu but CRichEditCtrl doesn't?

Tags: mfc

If you right-click in a standard MFC `CEdit` control you get a standard undo/cut/copy/paste/select-all context popup menu. But `CRichEditCtrl` doesn't provide the same thing as far as I can tell.

Is there any good reason why it was left out? Such a pain having to write custom controls to add in 'standard' functionality!

And how can it most easily be implemented? Is this a standard menu I can display or do I need to create my own menu from scratch to replicate the `CEdit` version?